# How to create new array without elements in certain range?

Tags: java

So I have a first and last variable which is the starting and ending markers that I want to get rid of. So the starting input for example would be
`[5, 10, 15, 20, 25]`
And say `first = 1` and `last = 3`. The would mean that the elements 10, 15, and 20 would not be included in the new array since they are at the indexes between 1-3, inclusive, so that new array without those nums would be the output. Here's what I have so far:

```
int [] newArr = new int[arr.length - (last - first) - 1];
for (int i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
     if (i < first || i > last) {
          newArr[i] = arr[i];
     }
}
```

They're just changing to 0's, and for some reason I can't think of what to do next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest approach is probably just to keep track of a separate index for where you are inserting elements into the new array.

```
int [] newArr = new int[arr.length - (last - first) - 1];
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     if (i < first || i > last) {
          newArr[j++] = arr[i];
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int [] newArr = new int[arr.length - (last - first) - 1];
    
    int count = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
         if (i < first || i > last) {
              newArr[count] = arr[i];
              count++;
         }
         
    }
```

The code you posted isn't working because newArr can't use i as the array index. Easiest way is to introduce a new count variable for this.

Answer (score 0):

## `Arrays.copyOfRange`

The utility class [`Arrays`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html) can help with your chore. The [`copyOfRange`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(int%5B%5D,int,int)) method gives you a subset of elements.

```java
int[] inputs = { 5 , 10 , 15 , 20 , 25 };
int first = 1, last = 3; // Inclusive (fully-closed).

int[] leading = Arrays.copyOfRange( inputs , 0 , first );
int[] trailing = Arrays.copyOfRange( inputs , last + 1 , inputs.length );
```

Dump to console.

```java
System.out.println( "leading = " + Arrays.toString( leading ) );
System.out.println( "trailing = " + Arrays.toString( trailing ) );
```

> leading = [5]
>
> trailing = [25]

You could [concatenate these two arrays in various ways](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=concatenate%20two%20arrays%20in%20java&t=osx&ia=web).

My own choice in modern Java would use streams ([`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html)) for brevity. If doing much of this, you might want to compare alternatives for performance.

```java
int[] result =
        IntStream.concat(
                        Arrays.stream( leading ) ,
                        Arrays.stream( trailing )
                )
                .toArray();
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "result = " + Arrays.toString( result ) );
```

> result = [5, 25]